# Problem with homepage's SEO when using subfolders in a multi language website

Tags: seo

After watching a hundreds of threads about **multilanguage website** I haven't found an answer to my specific problem, so I think its not a common issue and I must have done something terribly wrong ;-)

We have a brand.com website in DE main language and the following subfolders:

- /de/ = canonical of / + redirect to /
- /it/
- /en/

**When I crawl google.com for EN keywords or google.it for IT keywords then I get as results the homepage in German language (both title and description) as the top result with no trace of the /it/ or the /en/ homepage.**

Is this because /it/ and /en/ both needs a separate link building strategy?

I've already configured Google webmaster tool into the following way:

- brand.com, no language preference
- brand.com/de/, de language
- brand.com/it/, it language
- brand.com/en/, en language

Perhaps having "/" as DE main page is it wrong and I should use a different approach?
i.e. like having "/" to be a 301 to /de/ instead ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Content-Language meta tags as well on each of the subsites?

Comment: @paulmorriss yes, i'm using it, for example: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
<meta http-equiv='content-language' content='en' />`

Comment: @Antonio: what happens when you google 'site:brand.com/it/'or 'site:brand.com/en/'? Are your pages indexed?

Comment: @Ciaran yes i've 69.000 pages indexed an /it/ and /en/ are there using site:brand.com/en/ the page show 1st of the list with the right language and description

Comment: @Ciaran, @paulmorriss it could be that DMOZ listen me as oldbrand.it and i've some 301 redirect wrong? should i try adding robots header with NOODP?

Comment: Are the de, it, en sites supposed to have the same structure but with content in different languages? Or are they different (different numbers of pages for example)?

Comment: @Antonio, the NOODP tag would only affect the title and description for the site, so it shouldn't make a difference in this case.

I think it might be useful at this point to provide the link to your site so we can take a look. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: @Ciaran www.italiavacanze.com

Comment: @Antonio, you're using a Javascript redirect on the home page which will be ignored by Google: `<script>window.location="/en/";</script>`.

You need to change this to a correct 301 redirect on the server side.

I don't know if this will fix your problem entirely, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: @Ciaran, thanks i've already tested it without of it some weeks ago before posting :)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendations:

- delete content on current homepage brand.com and replace with a 301 redirect to the most important site, brand.com/de/, or a script that detects the browser language in use.
- remove geotargeting in Google Webmaster Tools, as really your site is multi-lingual rather than geotargetted.

  - > Please keep in mind that it generally does not make sense to set a geographic target if the same pages on your site target more than a single country (say, all German-speaking countries) — just write in that language and do not use the geotargeting setting (more on writing in other languages will follow soon!).
  - http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html
- remove canonical reference from brand.com/de/ to brand.com/
- invest in copywriting for the EN site. I don't speak German or Italian, but Google Translate shows the copy to be very different and more search-friendly on those sites than the English version.

Good luck!